Question in Topology without tears and the use of intersection to obtain singleton.
I am reading Topology without tears by Sidney A. Morris. I try to solve a problem about saturated set and $T_1$ space. This problem can be found at page 47, exercise 1.3, problem No. 10 (ii.).

Given a subset $S$ of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, call it saturated if it is an intersection of open set in $(X,\mathcal{T})$.

And the definition of $T_1$ space:

Given a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, it is a $T_1$ space if every singleton $\{x\}$ where $x\in X$ is closed.

The problem is state here:

Every set in $T_1$ space is saturated.

Given a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary points. $\fbox{If we can show that $\{x\}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$}$ then any $S\subseteq X$ can be see as intersection of $X$ and $\bigcup_{x\in S}\,\{x\}$. The latter is union of open set so turns out to be open set as well.
How to achieve:

Given topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ which is also $T_1$ and we let $x_0\in X$ be arbitrary point. We can choose other arbitrary point $x_1$ other than $x_0$ and considered its complement, i.e. $x_1 \in X\setminus \{x_0\}$ and its complement $X\setminus \{x_1\}$. Because $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is $T_1$ we know $X\setminus \{x_1\}$ is open. Since the intersection of two set will automatically turns out to either the smaller or the empty set we can apply this property. We can construct
$X\setminus \{x_1\}\cap X\setminus\{x_2\}\cap X\setminus\{x_3\}\cap ... \cap X\setminus\{x_n\}$
where $x_n$ is selected inductively like:
Let $x_1\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$ and for simplicity denote $\{x_0\} $by $P_0$. Similarly we have $\{x_0\}\cup\{x_\color{Red}{1}\}=P_\color{Red}{1}$.
Then we have $$x_1\in X\setminus P_0; \\
x_2\in X\setminus P_1; \\
x_n\in X\setminus P_{n-1}$$
By the way we choose $x_n$ we can ensure that $x_n$ run through all element in $X$ other than the initial $x_0$ and make the intersection defined above become smaller and smaller until it contains nothing but the singleton $\{x_0\}$. Since every set like $X\setminus\{x_n\}$ is open we know the intersection is open as well.
So we can apply intersection between $X$ and
$(X\setminus \{x_1\}\cap X\setminus\{x_2\}\cap X\setminus\{x_3\}\cap ... \cap X\setminus\{x_n\})=\{x_0\}$ to obtain the smaller set which is $\{x_0\}$, and it is open.

Is this argument workable? What about the situation when $X$ is infinite set which make the intersection defined above become too many? Is there a better way to express the same ideal? Thanks for the response!

Since $X$ is open in $(X,\tau)$ and $S\subseteq X\implies S=S\cap X$, isn't every subset of $X$ saturated, by your definition?

This definition makes more sense.

@JohnDouma I have seen this definition in another topology textbook but I think it is not the same concept since the definition I stated here is appear in Chapter 1 and the concept of quotient space have to wait until Chapter 11

You should probably replace the word "set" with "sets" in your definition.

In a general space $T_1$ the singleton are not open, an obvious counterexample is $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology: all the singleton $\{x\}$ are closed but not open, this is because (referring to your idea) the intersection of arbitrary numbers of open set does not need to be open.
Here's a proof of the exercise for a general topological space $(X, \tau)$: let $S$ be a subset of $X$, if we consider $S^C$ then $S^C= \cup_{x \in S^C}\{x\}$. Note that clearly we have: $\{x\}=(\{x\}^C)^C$ where the "$C$" means "complementary". Then:
$S^C=\cup_{x \in S^C}\{x\}=\cup_{x \in S^C}(\{x\}^C)^C=\cup_{x \in S^C}C(\{x\}^C)=C(\cap_{x \in S^C}\{x\}^C)$ (by De Morgan's laws). So we have that $S=\cap_{x \in S^C}\{x\}^C$. Since the space is $T_1$, we have that for every $x \in X, \ \{x\}^c$ is open in $(X, \tau)$.

We can do prove this by showing that the complement of any set is saturated. From that will follow the result because every set is the complement of its complement.
If $S=\emptyset$, then $S=\emptyset\cap X$ so $S$ is saturated.
If $S$ is a non-empty subset of $X$ then, for each $s\in S$, let $U_s$ be the complement of the singleton set $\{s\}$. Since singletons are closed in $T_1$ spaces, $U_s$ is open.
If $x$ is in the complement of $S$, denoted by $S^c$, then it is not equal to any $s\in S$, so $x\in U_s$ for all $s$. Conversely, if $x\in U_s$ for all $s$, then $x\not\in S$ so $x\in S^c$
Therefore, $S^c=\bigcap_{s\in S} U_s$ which is the intersection of open sets so $S^c$ is saturated. Therefore, the complement of any subset of $X$ is saturated and, since every set is the complement of its complement, $S$ is saturated.
